# How to make SQL server 2014 remember CTRL + ALT + Space behaviour at new tabs ? remember permanently?

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, ssms, sql-server-2014

Currently SQL server 2014 does remember `CTRL` + `ALT` + `Space` behaviour only at the tab you opened

When you open a new tab, it returns to the default behaviour

This is extremely annoying that each time i have to click `CTRL` + `ALT` + `Space` at each tab i have opened

So far i couldn't find a solution for SQL server 2014 Management Studio rememberim my choice forever

`CTRL` + `ALT` + `Space` makes intellisense  to choose your value automatically great time benefit

Ty very much for answers

if there is no manual way other way i opened a bug here so you can vote

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/955683/how-to-make-sql-server-2014-remember-ctrl-alt-space-behaviour-at-new-tabs-remember-permanently

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the Windows Update "SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 KB3058865" solved the issue for me.